# how to convert this T-SQL statment to linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i'm starter in linq, i have write this T-SQL Query

```
select * from DOCUMENT_TYPES where document_id in(
select document_id from Clearance_Document where Clearance_id=(select clearance_id from clearance_id from request where request_id=3))
```

i want convert this T-SQL Query to linq, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would start first by refactoring your SQL into something other than a chain of nested sub-queries. I think this ought to do the same thing, and it's much more readable:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    DOCUMENT_TYPES dt
JOIN
    Clearance_Document cd
    ON
    dt.document_id = cd.document_id
JOIN
    Request r
    ON
    cd.clearance_id = r.clearance_id
WHERE 
    r.request_id = 3
```

(I'm assuming that `from clearance_id from request` was a typo.)

Then you can easily refactor into a LINQ statement:

```
var result = from dt in DOCUMENT_TYPES
             join cd in Clearance_Document on dt.document_id equals cd.document_id
             join r in Request on cd.clearance_id equals r.clearance_id
             where r.request_id = 3
             select new {
                property1 = dt.something,
                property2 = cd.somethingElse,
                ...
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 

from  a in DOCUMENT_TYPES 
let list = 
(
from b in Clearance_Document 
where b.Clearance_id ==  (from c in clearance_id where  request_id == 3).First<string>())
select b
).ToList()

where list.Contains(a.document_id) 

select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do (i guessed you're using EF, but you can easyly adapt to other LinQ-Types):

```
context.Document_Types.Where(doc => 
  conext.Clearance_Document.Where(cd => 
    cd.Clearance_Id == context.Request.Single(r => r.Request_Id == 3)
  ).Contains(doc.Document_Id)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var result = c.Id context.Request.Single(r => r.Id == 3)
                .Clearances.SelectMany(c => x.DocumentTypes);
```

In effect, get the one and only `Request` with an `Id` equal to `3`, then get all the `DocumentTypes` of all its `Clearances`.

If your database is set up with the appropriate foreign keys these relationships will be automatically generated as part of your model.